# how to hide button, if the grid contains 'false' text in asp.net using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my asp.net web page i have a grid & button.

Code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvw" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No record(s) found">
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
         <ItemTemplate>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status">
         <ItemTemplate>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>                                            
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="view">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <div id='divView'>
          </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>                                            
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<input type="submit" id="btnView" runat="server" value="View">
```

the inner text of div View div(in 'view' column), that contains only one of the following two texts. 'true' and 'false'. if the text is 'true' then the submit button should be visible. else if the text is 'false' then the submit button should be hidden.

Comment: You're showing server-side code. This is a client-side code question. Your .NET code is irrelevant.

Comment: You could use the CssClass="false" property which would render class="false" and use that as your JQuery hook.

Comment: If you don't need to do this using jQuery or JS, you can just do it on the binding, by setting the Visible attribute dynamically.

Comment: You are repeating `<div id='divView'></div>` in a gridview control, So if you don't have the `input` button inside of the gridview you will end up having `multiple divView` VS `one btnView`!! then how would you say which inner text value of `divView` should change the `btnView` visibility!!!???  You must consider your question before you post it here.

Comment: button is in the grid view?